# Just/Fresh in for News

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for an expression to use for a piece of news that only was discovered very recently, similar to "breaking". Is it ok to use "just in " or "fresh in"? I feel like I heard something along those lines, but cannot remember the exact expression.

Example:

```
Just/Fresh in: After hours of diligent digging, Barki excavated an amazingly tasty bone!
```

Comment: It's  "just in: ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay to use "Just in" and "Fresh [not fresh in]" to refer to any new, recent news.

We use "Just in" to
announce breaking news; as it is an alternative phrase.

> This just in: "Mexico town's entire police force detained after
>   murder." ~BBC News

But the phrase "Fresh in" sounds wrong in having preposition "in". We use "fresh" to refer to any newly existed Novel, Book, article or news, etc.

Rather say:

> fresh news [not fresh in].

Additionally, you can also say:

> News-break: "Mexico town's entire police force detained after murder."
>   ~BBC News

**Note: this answer is kept as "community wiki", therefore, the corrections are welcomed wholeheartedly.**

Answer (score 0):

"Developing story" tends to garner interest at a glance, particularly as readers grow immune to "breaking news." My hunch is the connotation of ongoing coverage implies this must be something big, since we're already anticipating our covering it further and following it closely.